# How do I add new object or push into array Mongodb Compass NodeJS Express (update is not a function)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

At this moment I try to find the query which works in this case, but then want to update the object. So I want to check if review object exist and if not then create that key name first and then push that object into an array. Else push into that in existing object of array.

Default object looks like (without review object):

[image]

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const musicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    artist: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    release_year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    genre_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    image_url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    reviews: [{
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        locale: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        comment: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
});

const Music = mongoose.model("Music", musicSchema); // now we have to create our model 
console.log;

module.exports = Music;  // export our created model
```

```js
app.post('/addReview/:id', async (req, res) => {
  let idNumber = parseInt(req.params.id);  // 501437
  let reviewObject = req.body; // {id: "501437", locale: "nl", rating: 3, text: "helello"}
  try {
    const music = client.db('database').collection('music');
    const query = { id: idNumber };
    const musicSong = await music.findOne(query);
    await musicSong.update({ $push: { reviews: reviewObject } }); // error comes from here
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: So I want to check if review object exist and if not then create that key name first and then push that object into an array. Else push into that in existing object of array => This should happen by default with push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check if `reviews` field is not exists then initialise it to blank array
- push object to `reviews`
- `save()` to save main document

```
app.post('/addReview/:id', async (req, res) => {
  let idNumber = parseInt(req.params.id);  // 501437
  let reviewObject = req.body; // {id: "501437", locale: "nl", rating: 3, text: "helello"}
  try {
    const music = client.db('database').collection('music');
    const query = { id: idNumber };
    let musicSong = await music.findOne(query);
    if (!Array.isArray(musicSong.reviews)) {
      musicSong.reviews = [];
    }
    musicSong.reviews.push(reviewObject);
    music.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

---

**Second option using `updateOne()`:**

It does not require to find, check and save operations if you use update methods,

```
app.post('/addReview/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const query = { id: parseInt(req.params.id) };
  let reviewObject = req.body;
  try {
    const music = client.db('database').collection('music');
    await music.updateOne(query, { $push: { reviews: reviewObject } });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: music.save is not a function is what I reveive from the terminal

Comment: Yes, but still got that error tho. But when I do console.log(musicSong), it was pushed in the object.

Comment: okay i am not sure, check i have added another option as well.